# The fastest way to send a WebSocket broadcast to over 100,000 users

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, real-time

we have an app where there are around 100k connected users. What is the fastest way to send a WebSocket message from the server to all connected clients? We have tried with a loop but that is too slow.

What's an efficient way to do it using WebSocket API? **We are not looking to switch to GraphQL/AppSync or MQTT over IoT.**

We only have a couple of seconds for each broadcast to hit every connected user.

Any recommendations?

Thanks,

Comment: WebSocket runs on top of TCP, so there is no real broadcasting, you have no choice but to send a separate message to each connection individually. But, don't loop through them all sequentially 1 at a time, as you have already discovered. Send to them in parallel instead. For instance, put them into a queue and then use a handful of worker threads to pull them out of the queue. Or at least break them up into smaller groups that each thread can loop through more quickly. Otherwise, don't send the broadcast using WebSocket at all, use a more suitable protocol instead, like UDP Multicasting.

Comment: You created a point to point protocol and you don't want to switch.  Why?  If you insist on this architecture you'll be stuck with something like 1000's of Lambdas sending messages.

Comment: I have the same use case.. wanted to broadcast message to 5k users at the same time. Difference of 500ms is acceptable. I am using Apigateway websocket with lambda.